# AS3 Copy multidimensional arrays/Vector

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

I have two Vectors one called "SET_grid" which should never me changed and one called "tmp_grid" which can, but how do i copy SET_grid to tmp_grid without binding it to the original, so if tmp_grid change then the SET_gird doesn't, these Vectors are both multidimensional e.g.

```
 public var tmp_grid:Vector.<Vector.<node>>  = new Vector.<Vector.<node>>(2);
 public var SET_grid:Vector.<Vector.<node>>  = new Vector.<Vector.<node>>(2);
```

so i would use them like this....

```
tmp_grid[x][y].sayhello();

 tmp_grid = SET_grid does not work
 tmp_grid = SET_grid.concat(); //  nor does this one
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Nested arrays cannot be cloned without iterations. It's because they're nested :)
What this means is that you have to use nested loops and push to second vectors..

Comment: Sorry I havn't came onto the term nested before. What does this mean, and what is a nested loop or is there another way to do it? But thanks for the reply

Comment: It means Vector inside another Vector, or said in other words - multi dimensional vectors. It goes the same for loops - one loop inside another: `while(true) { while(true) { } }`. So you need two loops inside each other in order to loop through both Vectors (multi dimensional, each element is Vector by itself).